# How to store raster data outside postgis database

Tags: postgis, raster

I am able to import raster data easily into the database and view it through QGIS. However,
I am unable to view the raster layer in Arcgis.
Now I want to know how to create a table with a reference to raster files outside the datbaase. However, there isn't much discuss or example with regards to how it can be done.
I want to see its benefits given that raster layers can be shared across various applications.

Please share your knowledge on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the -R flag when using raster2pgsql to add the raster into PostGIS.  The -R flag indicates that the raster will be stored out-of-db.  All of the raster analysis functions in PostGIS will work but not the write functions, e.g. set pixel values, add bands.  In my limited testing, the performance of out-of-db rasters is slower than in-db.

http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/using_raster.xml.html#RT_Raster_Loader

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to view the table with arcmap. I could not see it because of the postgis raster data type. I thought since it only maintance  a reference to the images outside the database it might be just a geometry type. Any suggestion

Comment: If you're using out-of-db rasters, you don't need ArcGIS to call PostGIS.  Just point ArcGIS directly to the raster files themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In my work I store raster as a varchar pointing to the raster name, I use Django Framework (python) and as an example the procedure that I use is the following:

1) Have common path for the files ex: RASTER_PATH=/home/rasters
2) In the moment of creation the raster gets a hash name with py's hashlib (ex. 2d9e74148425752af7587c5b419542cb54480c49).
3) Only the name is stored in the DB. The file is stored in the RASTER_PATH.
4) When I need the raster I join the path with the name.
5) That's very versatile, I use the same name to create stores in GeoServer. And to create (hashed) layer names.

Comment: Thanks for your information pablo.I need to use ArcGIS. So, I am exploring better way of accessing raster data.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS uses the GDAL PostGIS Raster driver to display the data. I know it has a problem (I'm the developer of the driver). Actually working on it. Results expected before September.